# Speech (character) recognition in Delphi FMX

Tags: delphi, speech-recognition, firemonkey, speech-to-text, delphi-10.4-sydney

I need to recognize speech (only one letter/character, for example A, B, C, ...).

Does anybody have some idea how to do it?

My idea is, after clicking on a button, launch listening and when the user says something, ideally one letter, return this character. Improvement can be if the user says a whole word, functionality returns the first letter of this word.

I need this for an Android application, but if it can work in Windows 10 or 11, it will be nice.